# jQuery if statement, check if variable is true for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I was wondering whether I can trigger an if statement in jquery only if the variable is true for some time. Something like this if(variable == true //for #ms){do ..}. I'd need this in order not to trigger ajax post loading immediately.
Thanks in advance, Matt

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(function()
{
$('#reviewspostscont').each(
function()
{


    $(this).jScrollPane(
        {
            horizontalDragMaxWidth : 100
        }
    );
    var api = $(this).data('jsp');
    var throttleTimeout;
    $(window).bind(
        'resize',
        function()
        {
            if (!throttleTimeout) {
                throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                    function()
                    {
                        api.reinitialise();
                        throttleTimeout = null;
                    },
                    50
                );
            }
        }
    );
  var count = 2;

    $(this).bind(
        'jsp-scroll-x',
        function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight)
        {
        var count = 2;
            if (isAtRight == true) {
    ajaxJScrollLoader();
}


        }
    );

    function ajaxJScrollLoader()
    {
        api.getContentPane().append(
            loadArticle(count),
            count++
        );
        // we could call "pane.jScrollPane(settings)" again but it is
        // more convenient to call via the API as then the original
        // settings we passed in are automatically remembered.
        api.reinitialise();

    }

  }
 )




 });


 function loadArticle(pageNumber){    
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type:'POST',
                data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop-reviews', 
                success: function(html){
                    $(".jspPane").append(html);   // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                }
            });

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: You wrote your own answer...

Comment: This could be done a number of ways.  Where you set the variable to true/false would probably be a good place to start, but we need more context in order to give the best solution.

Comment: just added the whole script i've put together in the post

Comment: look at the variable isAtRight, i want it to trigger the function if that variable is true for like 3 sec

Answer (score 1):

You can use set interval function and check regularly:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
//Check what you want here
}, 1000);
```

The second parameter (1000) is time in miliseconds

If you need to stop this looping just do:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: nice but it doesnt seem to work, i mean, this checks if the variable is true every second but not if the variable stays true for 1 second, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So if you want this functionality you can check more often (f.e. 10 miliseconds) and start timer once the var has changed

Comment: can you make an example for the timer that starts when the variable changes please, that looks like exactly what i need sir

Answer (score 0):

You can begin a timeout when the variable is set to true.

Then every time the variable changes to false, stop the timeout, and restart the timeout when it is set to true again.

In the call-back of the timeout is where you would put your function that you want to fire after the variable is true for that period of time.